# Activemq scaling up on openshift is not working

Tags: openshift, activemq-classic, autoscaling

I have deployed an amq broker on openshift,
also I have enabled Auto-scaling for broker
when I send **1000** (or more) requests to test auto-scaling via apache jmeter, some problem is happening and my pod is crashing and some of my messages will be lost till another pod coming up.

image 1: (https://pasteboard.co/IyHxKH8.png)

image 2: (https://pasteboard.co/IyHyB68.png)

**Jmeter error:** Cannot send, channel has already failed: tcp://...

I know the error maybe appear beacause of maximumConnections=1000 in

```
<transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

1)The broker can not accept more than 1000 concurrent connection,but I don't know why it makes my pod to restart.

If I scale up my pod with :

```
oc scale dc broker-amq --replicas=3
```

and send request with 4000 thread simultaneously , each broker can accept 1000 concurrent connection so about 1000 request will be faild, but it does not make 3 pods to restart

2)another question is how can I make some changes in activemq.xml config file in openshift.

I used default template for amq deploying on openshift

3)Is it a correct way to test auto-scaling in activemq?

I really need to know the answer of questions,thanks alot.